# Antlr4 param-value parsing

Tags: antlr4

I'm new to antlr and trying to parse a file of mine (IBM Datastage export).

I have a working grammar but i'm not fully satisfied and I'm not sure I'm using antlr the right way :(

Here is an example of source file :

```
BEGIN HEADER
    CharacterSet "CP1252"
   ExportingTool "IBM InfoSphere DataStage Export"
   ToolVersion "8"
   ServerName "MIAIBV240"
   ToolInstanceID "DFDMGBL2"
   MDISVersion "1.0"
   Date "2018-02-12"
   Time "17.32.28"
   ServerVersion "8.7"
END HEADER
BEGIN DSJOB
    Identifier "job_FDM_WVD_NET_SALES_DSC_STG_REPL_Load"
   DateModified "2018-02-12"
   TimeModified "17.32.24"
   BEGIN DSRECORD
      Identifier "C52"
      OLEType "CContainerStage"
      Readonly "0"
      Name "ShcFileAudit_Verif_Data"
      NextID "3"
      BEGIN DSSUBRECORD
         Name "FDM_CMN"
         Description "#FDM_CMN#"
         ValueType "0"
      END DSSUBRECORD
      BEGIN DSSUBRECORD
         Name "FILE_NAME"
    FullDescription =+=+=+=#------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Description:

Some desc here .... 
#   Date                 Issue                         Version              
=+=+=+=
      JobVersion "56.0.0"
      ControlAfterSubr "0"
      Parameters "CParameters"
      END DSSUBRECORD
END DSRECORD
END DSJOB
```

As you can see it is mostly Key/value pairs.

I use this grammar :

```
grammar dsxGrammar;

dsxFile                 : headerDeclaration? jobDeclaration* EOF;
headerDeclaration       : BEGIN HEADER paramHeader* END HEADER;
jobDeclaration          : BEGIN DSJOB paramJob* recordDeclaration* paramJob* END DSJOB;
recordDeclaration       : BEGIN DSRECORD (paramRecord | subrecordDeclaration )* END DSRECORD;
subrecordDeclaration    : BEGIN DSSUBRECORD paramSubRecord* END DSSUBRECORD;
paramHeader             : PNAME PVALUE;
paramJob                : PNAME PVALUE;
paramRecord             : PNAME PVALUE;
paramSubRecord          : PNAME PVALUE;

//PVALUE         : '"' Text '"';
PVALUE          : '"' .*? '"';
BEGIN        : 'BEGIN';
END          : 'END';
HEADER       : 'HEADER';
DSJOB        : 'DSJOB';
DSRECORD     : 'DSRECORD';
DSSUBRECORD  : 'DSSUBRECORD';

ORCHCODE     : 'OrchestrateCode =+=+=+=' .*? '=+=+=+=' -> skip;
FULLDESC     : 'FullDescription =+=+=+=' .*? '=+=+=+=' -> skip;
VALUECODE    : 'Value =+=+=+=' .*? '=+=+=+=' -> skip;
EXPRCODE     : 'Expression =+=+=+=' .*? '=+=+=+=' -> skip;
DERIVCODE    : 'Derivation =+=+=+=' .*? '=+=+=+=' -> skip;
WS           : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
SPACE       : ' ';
COMMENT      : '/*' .*? '*/'    -> skip;
LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]*    -> skip;

//Identifier  : NONDIGIT ( NONDIGIT | DIGIT)*;
fragment Text        :   NONDIGIT ( SPACE | NONDIGIT | DIGIT)*;
fragment    NONDIGIT   :     [a-zA-Z_] ;
fragment DIGIT      :    [0-9];

PNAME        : ~["\\ \t\r\n]+;
```

It's working but i have to parse PNAME and PVALUE afterwards in my python code to extract double quotes, etc...
Is it the right way to do or I can do something with a Text fragment ?

I would like to have access to HeadProperty.PNAME and HeadProperty.PVALUE for example.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How are you processing it at the moment? Via a listener or visitor, or just manually walking the `ParseTree`?

Comment: I'm using a Listener based on the Listener generated by antlr. I'm wondering about walking the ParseTree but it seems better with Listener ? What's your opinion ?

Comment: In this case, I'd go for a visitor that return custom domain objects instead of a listener. Shall I post a quick demo of how I'd go about it?

Comment: Of course you can ! go head, i'm looking forward to your example :)

Answer (score 0):

> [...] Is it the right way to do or I can do something with a Text fragment ?

Not in the grammar (at least, not without using target specific code). You'll have to change the text in a listener or visitor. In your case, I'd go for a visitor. The code below is in Java, but should be easily converted to Python.

First a couple of remarks about your current grammar:

- lexer rules like these `'OrchestrateCode =+=+=+='` can be fragile. If the input contains something like this: `OrchestrateCode  =+=+=+=` (2 spaces), it won't be tokenised properly
- your rule `SPACE : ' ';` is only used in a `fragment`, so it should also be a `fragment`
- you're repeating `PNAME PVALUE` quite a lot in your parser rules: I'd create a `keyValues` rule for it (this also simplifies the visitor which I'll add below)
- the same for `=+=+=+=` in your lexer rule: I'd create a `fragment` that matches this ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!)

It looks like a lot of feedback, but they're all minor points. Given that you're new to ANTLR, I think you did a good job.

OK, given the points above, your grammar could look like this:

```antlr
grammar dsxGrammar;

dsxFile              : headerDeclaration? jobDeclaration* EOF;
headerDeclaration    : BEGIN HEADER paramHeaders=keyValues END HEADER;
jobDeclaration       : BEGIN DSJOB paramJob+=keyValues recordDeclaration* paramJob+=keyValues END DSJOB;
recordDeclaration    : BEGIN DSRECORD ( paramRecord+=keyValue | subrecordDeclaration )* END DSRECORD;
subrecordDeclaration : BEGIN DSSUBRECORD paramSubRecords=keyValues END DSSUBRECORD;
keyValues            : keyValue*;
keyValue             : PNAME PVALUE;

PVALUE       : '"' .*? '"';
BEGIN        : 'BEGIN';
END          : 'END';
HEADER       : 'HEADER';
DSJOB        : 'DSJOB';
DSRECORD     : 'DSRECORD';
DSSUBRECORD  : 'DSSUBRECORD';

ORCHCODE     : 'OrchestrateCode' SPACE* SEPARATOR .*? SEPARATOR -> skip;
FULLDESC     : 'FullDescription' SPACE* SEPARATOR .*? SEPARATOR -> skip;
VALUECODE    : 'Value' SPACE* SEPARATOR .*? SEPARATOR -> skip;
EXPRCODE     : 'Expression' SPACE* SEPARATOR .*? SEPARATOR -> skip;
DERIVCODE    : 'Derivation' SPACE* SEPARATOR .*? SEPARATOR -> skip;
WS           : SPACE+ -> skip;
COMMENT      : '/*' .*? '*/'    -> skip;
LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]*    -> skip;
PNAME        : ~["\\ \t\r\n]+;

fragment NONDIGIT  : [a-zA-Z_] ;
fragment DIGIT     : [0-9];
fragment SPACE     : [ \t\r\n\u000C];
fragment SEPARATOR : '=+=+=+=';
```

You might notice the *labels* in the parser rules, like `paramSubRecords=...` and `paramJob+=...`. These are good for 2 things:

1. readability of your grammar (`keyValues` doesn't mean much, while it's clear what `keyValues` really is in case `paramSubRecords=keyValues` is written)
2. in your listener or visitor, you can reference these *labeled* children from a parent context. Say you have the rule

   ```antlr
   foo : first=PNAME second=PNAME;
   ```

   then you can do this in a visitor:

   ```java
   @Override
   public Object visitFoo(dsxGrammarParser.FooContext ctx) {
     String firstName = ctx.first.getText();
     String secondName = ctx.second.getText();
     ...
   }
   ```

   And if you have a `+=` in there like this:

   ```antlr
   foo : allJobs+=jobDeclaration+ PNAME allJobs+=jobDeclaration+;
   ```

   then all `jobDeclaration` contexts are added in a `java.util.List` you can use in the parent context:

   ```java
   @Override
   public Object visitFoo(dsxGrammarParser.FooContext ctx) {
     List<dsxGrammarParser.JobDeclarationContext> jobs = ctx.allJobs;
     ...
   }
   ```

If you now generate a visitor from the updated grammar, you can test it like this:

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "BEGIN HEADER\n" +
        "    CharacterSet \"CP1252\"\n" +
        "   ExportingTool \"IBM InfoSphere DataStage Export\"\n" +
        "   ToolVersion \"8\"\n" +
        "   ServerName \"MIAIBV240\"\n" +
        "   ToolInstanceID \"DFDMGBL2\"\n" +
        "   MDISVersion \"1.0\"\n" +
        "   Date \"2018-02-12\"\n" +
        "   Time \"17.32.28\"\n" +
        "   ServerVersion \"8.7\"\n" +
        "END HEADER\n" +
        "BEGIN DSJOB\n" +
        "    Identifier \"job_FDM_WVD_NET_SALES_DSC_STG_REPL_Load\"\n" +
        "   DateModified \"2018-02-12\"\n" +
        "   TimeModified \"17.32.24\"\n" +
        "   BEGIN DSRECORD\n" +
        "      Identifier \"C52\"\n" +
        "      OLEType \"CContainerStage\"\n" +
        "      Readonly \"0\"\n" +
        "      Name \"ShcFileAudit_Verif_Data\"\n" +
        "      NextID \"3\"\n" +
        "      BEGIN DSSUBRECORD\n" +
        "         Name \"FDM_CMN\"\n" +
        "         Description \"#FDM_CMN#\"\n" +
        "         ValueType \"0\"\n" +
        "      END DSSUBRECORD\n" +
        "      BEGIN DSSUBRECORD\n" +
        "         Name \"FILE_NAME\"\n" +
        "    FullDescription =+=+=+=#------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Description:\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Some desc here .... \n" +
        "#   Date                 Issue                         Version              \n" +
        "=+=+=+=\n" +
        "      JobVersion \"56.0.0\"\n" +
        "      ControlAfterSubr \"0\"\n" +
        "      Parameters \"CParameters\"\n" +
        "      END DSSUBRECORD\n" +
        "END DSRECORD\n" +
        "END DSJOB";

    dsxGrammarLexer lexer = new dsxGrammarLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    dsxGrammarParser parser = new dsxGrammarParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    DsxFile dsxFile = new MapVisitor().visitDsxFile(parser.dsxFile());
    System.out.println(dsxFile);
  }
}

class MapVisitor extends dsxGrammarBaseVisitor<Object> {

  // dsxFile              : headerDeclaration? jobDeclaration* EOF;
  @Override
  public DsxFile visitDsxFile(dsxGrammarParser.DsxFileContext ctx) {

    Map<String, String> headerDeclaration = visitHeaderDeclaration(ctx.headerDeclaration());
    List<JobDeclaration> jobDeclarations = new ArrayList<>();

    if (ctx.jobDeclaration() != null) {
      for (dsxGrammarParser.JobDeclarationContext child : ctx.jobDeclaration()) {
        jobDeclarations.add(visitJobDeclaration(child));
      }
    }

    return new DsxFile(headerDeclaration, jobDeclarations);
  }

  // headerDeclaration    : BEGIN HEADER paramHeaders=keyValues END HEADER;
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> visitHeaderDeclaration(dsxGrammarParser.HeaderDeclarationContext ctx) {
    return visitKeyValues(ctx.paramHeaders);
  }

  // jobDeclaration       : BEGIN DSJOB paramJob+=keyValues recordDeclaration* paramJob+=keyValues END DSJOB;
  @Override
  public JobDeclaration visitJobDeclaration(dsxGrammarParser.JobDeclarationContext ctx) {

    Map<String, String> paramJobs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<RecordDeclaration> recordDeclarations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (dsxGrammarParser.KeyValuesContext child : ctx.paramJob) {
      paramJobs.putAll(visitKeyValues(child));
    }

    for (dsxGrammarParser.RecordDeclarationContext child : ctx.recordDeclaration()) {
      recordDeclarations.add(visitRecordDeclaration(child));
    }

    return new JobDeclaration(paramJobs, recordDeclarations);
  }

  // recordDeclaration    : BEGIN DSRECORD ( paramRecord+=keyValue | subrecordDeclaration )* END DSRECORD;
  @Override
  public RecordDeclaration visitRecordDeclaration(dsxGrammarParser.RecordDeclarationContext ctx) {

    Map<String, String> paramRecords = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<Map<String, String>> subrecordDeclarations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (dsxGrammarParser.KeyValueContext child : ctx.paramRecord) {
      String[] keyValue = visitKeyValue(child);
      paramRecords.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }

    for (dsxGrammarParser.SubrecordDeclarationContext child : ctx.subrecordDeclaration()) {
      subrecordDeclarations.add(visitSubrecordDeclaration(child));
    }

    return new RecordDeclaration(paramRecords, subrecordDeclarations);
  }

  // subrecordDeclaration : BEGIN DSSUBRECORD paramSubRecords=keyValues END DSSUBRECORD;
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> visitSubrecordDeclaration(dsxGrammarParser.SubrecordDeclarationContext ctx) {
    return visitKeyValues(ctx.paramSubRecords);
  }

  // keyValues            : keyValue*;
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> visitKeyValues(dsxGrammarParser.KeyValuesContext ctx) {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    if (ctx.keyValue() != null) {
      for (dsxGrammarParser.KeyValueContext child : ctx.keyValue()) {
        String[] keyValue = visitKeyValue(child);
        map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
      }
    }

    return map;
  }

  // keyValue             : PNAME PVALUE;
  @Override
  public String[] visitKeyValue(dsxGrammarParser.KeyValueContext ctx) {
    return new String[] {
        ctx.PNAME().getText(),
        ctx.PVALUE().getText().substring(1, ctx.PVALUE().getText().length() - 1)
    };
  }
}

// headerDeclaration? jobDeclaration* EOF
class DsxFile {

  final Map<String, String> headerDeclaration;
  final List<JobDeclaration> jobDeclarations;

  DsxFile(Map<String, String> headerDeclaration, List<JobDeclaration> jobDeclarations) {
    this.headerDeclaration = headerDeclaration;
    this.jobDeclarations = jobDeclarations;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "DsxFile{" +
        "\n  headerDeclaration=" + headerDeclaration +
        "\n  jobDeclarations=" + jobDeclarations +
        "\n}";
  }
}

// BEGIN DSJOB paramJob+=keyValues recordDeclaration* paramJob+=keyValues END DSJOB
class JobDeclaration {

  final Map<String, String> paramJobs;
  final List<RecordDeclaration> recordDeclarations;

  JobDeclaration(Map<String, String> paramJobs, List<RecordDeclaration> recordDeclarations) {
    this.paramJobs = paramJobs;
    this.recordDeclarations = recordDeclarations;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "\n    JobDeclaration{" +
        "\n      paramJobs=" + paramJobs +
        "\n      recordDeclarations=" + recordDeclarations +
        "\n    }";
  }
}

// BEGIN DSRECORD ( paramRecord+=keyValue | subrecordDeclaration )* END DSRECORD
class RecordDeclaration {

  final Map<String, String> paramRecords;
  final List<Map<String, String>> subrecordDeclarations;

  RecordDeclaration(Map<String, String> paramRecords, List<Map<String, String>> subrecordDeclarations) {
    this.paramRecords = paramRecords;
    this.subrecordDeclarations = subrecordDeclarations;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "\n        RecordDeclaration{" +
        "\n          paramRecords=" + paramRecords +
        "\n          subrecordDeclarations=" + subrecordDeclarations +
        "\n        }";
  }
}
```

If you run the main class, you'll see the following being printed to your console:

```
DsxFile{
  headerDeclaration={CharacterSet=CP1252, ExportingTool=IBM InfoSphere DataStage Export, ToolVersion=8, ServerName=MIAIBV240, ToolInstanceID=DFDMGBL2, MDISVersion=1.0, Date=2018-02-12, Time=17.32.28, ServerVersion=8.7}
  jobDeclarations=[
    JobDeclaration{
      paramJobs={Identifier=job_FDM_WVD_NET_SALES_DSC_STG_REPL_Load, DateModified=2018-02-12, TimeModified=17.32.24}
      recordDeclarations=[
        RecordDeclaration{
          paramRecords={Identifier=C52, OLEType=CContainerStage, Readonly=0, Name=ShcFileAudit_Verif_Data, NextID=3}
          subrecordDeclarations=[{Name=FDM_CMN, Description=#FDM_CMN#, ValueType=0}, {Name=FILE_NAME, JobVersion=56.0.0, ControlAfterSubr=0, Parameters=CParameters}]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Wow so much work, thanks ! I will take some time to analyse this. At first glance, i prefer using a listnener but i'll check this visitor. Perhaps with listener i can't get the full list of keyValues at once.

Comment: Yeah, while I was writing it up, it got longer and longer (let me know if there's something unclear). Sure, if listeners work for you, go with listeners! I'm sure there's something in my answer that benefits you, and of course any future readers of this Q&A.